# Files disappearing from Amazon EC2 servers

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-computing

I have an Ubuntu 8.10 server at Amazon's EC2, based on the [ami-1c5db975](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1427) image by Eric Hammond.

After rebooting an EC2 server, the `/etc/resolv.conf` file is reset to a default, erasing any changes made prior to the boot.

This bug was told to be secluded [problem related only to Canonical Ubuntu image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891290/lost-modified-etc-hosts-file-on-amazon-ec2-every-reboot-instance), which I don't use.

1. Do you know of any other files affected by reboot?
2. Is there any workaround or proper solution for this bug?

Thanks,

Udi

**EDIT: Problem solved, 1 month later:**

Thanks for your answers and comments. I did edit the dhcp3 configuration file, but forgot to restart dhcp3:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

After running this, the `resolv.conf` file was automatically updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

/etc/resolv.conf is reset by the DHCP client. If you want to override it, you might want to look into using [resolvconf](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=resolvconf) to prepend custom configuration. Note that if you override Amazon's DNS servers, transfers to/from S3 may no longer be free.

Comment: If you're a hand-editing type, the file you want is /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there's no way that change will persist unless you're storing it on an EBS volume. If you don't want to use EBS, you can use a different AMI image that serves your needs, or you can run a post-boot script that changes that file.

Comment: Not true. EC2 data persists during a reboot. It disappears if you shutdown or terminate an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... amazon EC2 aren't persistent. If you want a persistent file system, use Amazon EBD with your EC2.

Or am I misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 0):

Images are not persistant. Configuration should be fetched automatically from S3 (or elsewhere) at boot time. Some configuration can also be sent at boot time with the user-data parameter, see for example http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1085 (Using Parameterized Launches to Customize Your AMIs)